# How do I copy an Image from one Doc to another with OpenXML and C#?

Tags: c#, image, openxml

I (OpenXML Newbie) need to extend a program which expands own templates.  There is a table with person name and a description. The description should be taken from another document. This part works fine with unformatted text.

Now the customer wants to use formatted text and pictures in the description part. 
The formatting works, but I couldn't get the image part to work.  Word 2007 couldn't open the document any more.

I assume that something with the relationship went wrong. I found two parts in the XML which smell:

- In the original document the image was in the path: `/word/media/image1.bin` now in the generated doc the image is in `/media/image.bin`. Can this cause a problem?  In  `/word/_rels/document.xml` the path points to correct ressource: `Target="/media/image.bin"`
- Word seems to loose the "pic" namespace: In the generated doc I have the tags: `<a:pic>, <a:nvPicPr>, ...` instead of `<pic:pic>, <pic:ncvPicPr>, ...`

Can you please help me, with this issue or point me to a tutorial ressource? Because large parts of the document already exist I am constricted in the way to implement this (e.g. I have to return a TableCell).

### Edit:

I just edited the generated document.xml by hand: I replaced the `<a:...>` with `<pic:...>` and now it seems to work. So the problem is how to generate the `<pic:...>` elements correctly.

Here are some code snippets regarding the relationship:

```
...
ImagePart myIP = mainPart.AddImagePart(iP.ContentType);
// mIPRelId is a string which ist later used (blip)
mIPRelId = mainPart.CreateRelationshipToPart(myIP); 

// iP is the imagepart from the source doc...
myIP.FeedData(iP.GetStream());                  
// myDR is the local drawing
// generate Inline should generate the inline part 
myDR.Inline = generateInline(myXMLDrawing, nsManager);
...
// later when generating the blip
if (myChild.Name == "a:blip")
{
    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Blip myBlip = new Blip();
    myBlip.Embed = mIPRelId;
    ...
    myBlipFill.Append(myBlip);
 }
```

Here is the snippet that generates the picture part (namespace prob):

```
 ...
 DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Picture myPic = 
    new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Picture();
 string myNodes = ".//descendant::pic:nvPicPr | ";
        myNodes += ".//descendant::pic:blipFill | ";
        myNodes += ".//descendant::pic:spPr | ";
        myNodes += ".//following::w:bookmarkEnd";

 XmlNodeList followingNodesList = myXMLPic.
               SelectNodes(myNodes, nsManager);

 myPic.AddNamespaceDeclaration(
                   "pic", 
                   "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture");


  // stepping through the descendants and adding them
  // to the picture
  foreach (XmlElement el in followingNodesList)
  {
      if (el.Name == "pic:nvPicPr")
      {
         DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.NonVisualPictureProperties myNVPP = 
                                                  new NonVisualPictureProperties();
         ...
         myPic.Append(myNVPP);
      }
      ...          
      // Adding the other parts like blipfill....
```

Here is a snippet of the generated XML (sorry for the formatting):

```
 ...
 <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
   <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
     <a:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
       <a:nvPicPr>
         <a:cNvPr id="0" name="MS_HUND.JPG" /> 
         <a:cNvPicPr /> 
       </a:nvPicPr>
       <a:blipFill>
         <a:blip r:embed="R65532bbe7935423e" cstate="print" /> 
         <a:stretch>
           <a:fillRect /> 
         </a:stretch>
       </a:blipFill>
       <a:spPr>
         <a:xfrm>
           <a:off x="0" y="0" /> 
           <a:ext cx="714375" cy="762000" /> 
         </a:xfrm>
         <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
           <a:avLst /> 
         </a:prstGeom>
       </a:spPr>
     </a:pic>
   </a:graphicData>
 </a:graphic>
 ...
```

Comment: Problem ist solved: picture should be from DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Pictures.Picture